# Interpreting a 3 dimensional Graph?

Tags: calculus

The points P(a, b, c) and Q(2, 3, 5) are symmetric
in the sense given. Find a, b, c.
About the xy-plane.

How does one find the answer to this without graphing. I just do not understand how one would be able to just get the answer by looking at the graph.[image]

Comment: symmetric in what sense given? Symmetric about the xy plane probably just means reflected to the opposite z value.

Comment: Then the answer would be P( 2, 3 ,-5)? What I do not understand is why they cannot just say what you said. Is there a list that shows us what it means when it say about the xy plane? Or xz plane?

Comment: In a book which describes algebraic transformations of functions, that is the language they use for, say, reflection about the x axis. I'm not sure if they definve the language in the vector calc book I use. But it's not unusual for a concept like that to be generalized to a different context without being specifically redefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm agree with $jdods$. Is just a reflection, as the plane $xy$ were a mirror, or any plane. If they ask you to find the point but using the $xz$ plane  it would be (2,-3,5).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_symmetry